# How to exclude a supplier if it returns two values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a clause to restrict the data returned.

if AUTHORIZATION_STATUS from PO_headers_all returns STATUS 'approved' and 'in process' then do not return supplier. however it it returns as 'approved' on its own I need the supplier to be returned.

The purpose of this is to return suppliers that do not have outstanding PO against them.

Is there a way of doing this?

```
Select
    company,
     vendor_site_code,
    vendor_name,
    segment1,
    Site_Type,
    Max_Invoice_Date,
    TEST
  From 
(
select
    inv.org_id  company,
    ps.vendor_site_code,
    pv.vendor_name,
    pv.segment1,
    inv.org_id,
 --  CASE  WHEN pha.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS IN ( 'APPROVED', 'IN PROCESS') THEN 'ACTIVE'
  --       ELSE 'IN ACTIVE' end AS TEST,
    ps.pay_group_lookup_code AS Site_Type,
    MAX (inv.gl_date) AS Max_Invoice_Date,
    1 As unit_ 
        from  ap_invoices_all inv,
          po_vendors pv,
         po_vendor_sites_all ps,
         PO_headers_all pha
        where inv.vendor_id = pv.vendor_id
        and pv.vendor_id = ps.vendor_id
        and inv.vendor_site_id = ps.vendor_site_id
        and pha.vendor_id = pv.vendor_id
        and inv.org_id in (174,169,172)
        and ps.inactive_date is null
        and pv.END_DATE_ACTIVE is null
GROUP BY
    inv.org_id,
    ps.vendor_site_code,
    pv.vendor_name,
    pv.segment1,
    ps.pay_group_lookup_code,
    inv.org_id,
    --CASE  WHEN pha.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS IN ( 'APPROVED', 'IN PROCESS') THEN 'ACTIVE'
       --  ELSE 'IN ACTIVE' end
    ORDER BY vendor_name DESC
)
WHERE
 Max_Invoice_Date <  TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -12 ),'MONTH')
```

an example output is below;

```
172|UMANIS.201|UMANIS|COMPUTER|12988|EXPENSE|24-NOV-11|APPROVED
172|UMANIS.201|UMANIS|COMPUTER|12988|EXPENSE|24-NOV-11|IN PROCESS
```

I would like to exclude the supplier if the results are like the above.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Why doesn't a simple `where` clause work?

Comment: `not in ('approved', 'in process')` ?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff. The query is to show suppliers that have no purchase orders outstanding against them. If a supplier has a PO 'in process' and 'approved' then this supplier need to be excluded due to reports main focus is deactivate non trading suppliers that have no outstanding PO's against them

Comment: I'd be tempted to answer "yes, there is" :-) I could say you could just use a "SELECT * FROM SUPPLIERS WHERE SUPPLIER_ID NOT IN (SELECT SUPPLIER_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE STATUS IN ('approved', 'in process')) ... But you' d really better edit the question and put some table names and structure (and possibly data) to allow you to compare the answers from the different people who are willing to help

Comment: HI @Insac, i hope the above make sense

Comment: It's really hard to understand your need this way. Please post some sample data and desired result; this will help us in answering your question

Comment: @Aleksej please see edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's dive in.

But first a necessary pointer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

You can find (and hopefully, correct, complete and add into your question) an attempt of such an example in this answer (also on [rextester](http://rextester.com/EORAT45177)). The example could be extensively simplified as lots of the fields don't really relate to your core question ("How can I filter records where the condition is the existence of two related records in another table?") but on your specific business requirements.

I decided not to simplify anything, because I wanted to be able to test *exactly* the query you have put into the question.

I've tried to recreate the sample data from what you said, from the query and the sample output.

I've created 2 vendors: UMANIS (whose header status contains both "APPROVED" and "IN PROCESS", and thus it should be filtered out) and ROBOZ (whose header status contains only "APPROVED" and thus it should be returned).

```
 create table ap_invoices_all (
     org_id integer,
     gl_date date,
     vendor_id integer,
     vendor_site_id integer
 );

 insert into ap_invoices_all (org_id, gl_date, vendor_id, vendor_site_id)
                      values (172   , to_date('2015-04-27','YYYY-MM-DD'), 111, 201);                  
 insert into ap_invoices_all (org_id, gl_date, vendor_id, vendor_site_id)
                      values (172   , to_date('2015-03-11','YYYY-MM-DD'), 222, 301);


 create table po_vendors (
     vendor_name     varchar2(20),
     segment1        varchar2(20),
     vendor_id       integer,
     end_date_active date 
 );

 insert into po_vendors (vendor_id, vendor_name, segment1, end_date_active)
                 values (111, 'UMANIS','SEGM1',null);

 insert into po_vendors (vendor_id, vendor_name, segment1, end_date_active)
                 values (222, 'ROBOZ','SEGM1',null);

 create table po_vendor_sites_all (
     vendor_site_code      varchar2(20),
     pay_group_lookup_code varchar2(20),
     vendor_id integer,
     vendor_site_id integer,
     inactive_date date
 );

 insert into po_vendor_sites_all (vendor_id, vendor_site_id, vendor_site_code, pay_group_lookup_code, inactive_date)
                 values (111, 201, 'UMANIS.201', 'EXPENSE',null);

 insert into po_vendor_sites_all (vendor_id, vendor_site_id, vendor_site_code, pay_group_lookup_code, inactive_date)
                 values (222, 301, 'ROBOZ.301', 'EXPENSE',null);

 create table po_headers_all (
     vendor_id integer,
     AUTHORIZATION_STATUS varchar2(20)
 );

 insert into po_headers_all (vendor_id, AUTHORIZATION_STATUS)
                 values (111, 'APPROVED');
 insert into po_headers_all (vendor_id, AUTHORIZATION_STATUS)
                 values (111, 'IN PROCESS');
 insert into po_headers_all (vendor_id, AUTHORIZATION_STATUS)
                 values (222, 'APPROVED');


 -- Original query     
 Select
     company,
     vendor_site_code,
     vendor_name,
     segment1,
     Site_Type,
     Max_Invoice_Date,
     TEST
   From 
 (
 select
     inv.org_id  company,
     ps.vendor_site_code,
     pv.vendor_name,
     pv.segment1,
     inv.org_id,
    CASE  WHEN pha.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS IN ( 'APPROVED', 'IN PROCESS') THEN 'ACTIVE'
          ELSE 'IN ACTIVE' end AS TEST,
     ps.pay_group_lookup_code AS Site_Type,
     MAX (inv.gl_date) AS Max_Invoice_Date,
     1 As unit_ 
         from  ap_invoices_all inv,
           po_vendors pv,
          po_vendor_sites_all ps,
          PO_headers_all pha
         where inv.vendor_id = pv.vendor_id
         and pv.vendor_id = ps.vendor_id
         and inv.vendor_site_id = ps.vendor_site_id
         and pha.vendor_id = pv.vendor_id
         and inv.org_id in (174,169,172)
         and ps.inactive_date is null
         and pv.END_DATE_ACTIVE is null
 GROUP BY
     inv.org_id,
     ps.vendor_site_code,
     pv.vendor_name,
     pv.segment1,
     ps.pay_group_lookup_code,
     inv.org_id,
     CASE  WHEN pha.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS IN ( 'APPROVED', 'IN PROCESS') THEN 'ACTIVE'
          ELSE 'IN ACTIVE' end
     ORDER BY vendor_name DESC
 )
 WHERE
  Max_Invoice_Date <  TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -12 ),'MONTH');

 -- proposed query     
 Select
     company,
     vendor_site_code,
     vendor_name,
     segment1,
     Site_Type,
     Max_Invoice_Date,
     TEST
   From 
 (
 select
     inv.org_id  company,
     ps.vendor_site_code,
     pv.vendor_name,
     pv.segment1,
     inv.org_id,
    CASE  WHEN pha_app.vendor_id is not null or pha_proc.vendor_id is not null THEN 'ACTIVE'
          ELSE 'IN ACTIVE' end AS TEST,
     ps.pay_group_lookup_code AS Site_Type,
     MAX (inv.gl_date) AS Max_Invoice_Date,
     1 As unit_ 
         from  ap_invoices_all inv
               inner join po_vendors pv 
                       on inv.vendor_id = pv.vendor_id
               inner join po_vendor_sites_all ps 
                       on inv.vendor_site_id = ps.vendor_site_id 
                      and pv.vendor_id = ps.vendor_id
                left join po_headers_all pha_app
                       on pha_app.vendor_id = pv.vendor_id
                      and pha_app.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS='APPROVED'
                left join po_headers_all pha_proc
                       on pha_proc.vendor_id = pv.vendor_id
                      and pha_proc.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS='IN PROCESS'
         where inv.org_id in (174,169,172)
         and ps.inactive_date is null
         and pv.END_DATE_ACTIVE is null
         and (pha_app.vendor_id is not null and pha_proc.vendor_id is null)
 GROUP BY
     inv.org_id,
     ps.vendor_site_code,
     pv.vendor_name,
     pv.segment1,
     ps.pay_group_lookup_code,
     inv.org_id,
     CASE  WHEN pha_app.vendor_id is not null or pha_proc.vendor_id is not null THEN 'ACTIVE'
          ELSE 'IN ACTIVE' end
     ORDER BY vendor_name DESC
 )
 WHERE
  Max_Invoice_Date <  TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -12 ),'MONTH');
```

the first query returns

```
 COMPANY VENDOR_SITE_CODE   VENDOR_NAME SEGMENT1 SITE_TYPE MAX_INVOICE_DATE     TEST 
 172     UMANIS.201         UMANIS      SEGM1    EXPENSE   27.04.2015 00:00:00  ACTIVE
 172     ROBOZ.301          ROBOZ       SEGM1    EXPENSE   11.03.2015 00:00:00  ACTIVE
```

the second one returns just ROBOZ

```
 COMPANY VENDOR_SITE_CODE   VENDOR_NAME SEGMENT1 SITE_TYPE MAX_INVOICE_DATE     TEST 
 172     ROBOZ.301          ROBOZ       SEGM1    EXPENSE   11.03.2015 00:00:00  ACTIVE
```

As for an explanation of the logic of the second query (my proposed solution), I'm so tired now (00:37 AM) that I just joined the pha_headers twice, once for "APPROVED" records and once for "IN PROCESS" records, so I could use them as simple joins, all on the same record.

Other solutions are possible, without having to access the table twice ("pivoting" the table with aggregate function and CASE for example)

Comment: You're welcome. So,  are you going to accept this answer or there is something that still doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes i have accepted this as the answer. I apprecicate taking the time to tackle this as I am still a beginner in this world.